# how can I include head of column in a csv export file from mapreduce

Tags: google-app-engine

I am exporting a file using mapreduce and work properly but I would like include head of column with a description How can I do it. andy idea.

Comment: Post some code and explain what you've tried...

Comment: I have developed similara python app similar to log2bq [http://log2bq.appspot.com/ this app export a csv file similar spreedsheet . The problemn is that export not contain column description only rows of dat and I will need put head.                                           Head, Date,  Name,  Surname
row1, 2001-10-01,  peter,  sanz
row2, 2001-10-22,  jose,   perez